# Why 3 +++ 5 works in Python

Tags: python, evaluation

```
In [476]: 3 + 5
Out[476]: 8

In [477]: 3 +++++++++++++++++++++ 5
Out[477]: 8

In [478]: 3 + + + + + + + + + + + 5
Out[478]: 8

In [479]: 3 +++ --- +++ --- +++ 5
Out[479]: 8
```

Why there is no `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` or `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +` error?

I know this handled in compile process, but how it works?

Answer (score 6):

Using `ast` module we can create abstract syntax tree presentation and see what happens:

```
import ast
source = 'ADD SOURCE HERE'
node = ast.parse(source, mode='eval')
ast.dump(node, False, False)
```

In the case of `3 +++ 5`, AST generates the following expression:

```
'Expression(BinOp(Num(1), Add(), UnaryOp(UAdd(), UnaryOp(UAdd(), Num(2)))))'
```

Or for example `3 ++ -- 5` produces:

```
'Expression(BinOp(Num(3), Add(), UnaryOp(UAdd(), UnaryOp(USub(), Num(-5)))))'
```

Comment: I wonder if 3 ------------ 5 takes longer to calculate than 3 - 5. I don't have time to benchmark now...

Comment: @zmbq yes, it does. the disassembly shows that `UNARY_NEGATIVE` is called several times.

Comment: I guess Python can't be sure that `--x == x`

Comment: @zmbq As Hiro described in the other answer, Python can't optimize those since operators can be overloaded. And for that reason `--x` may not always be equal to`x` -- that must be determined in runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Beause if there are more than one operator between operand then it will work as below

```
3 +++ 5  # it will work as 3 + ( + ( +5) )
```

Hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `3 -- 5` produces `8`, while `3 --- 5` is `-2`, so obviously unary operators `+` and `-` work exactly as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
+ obj
```

will call the *unary* `__pos__(self)` (just as `- obj` calls `__neg__(self)`. repeated `+` and `-` before `obj` will call those repeatedly.

```
++++++-+++++ 5  # = -5
```

in your expression

```
3 +++++++++++++++++++++ 5
```

the left-most operator will then call the *binary* `__add__` (or `__sub__`). so there is no ambiguity and no reason for this to raise an error.

the python interpreter does not optimize these calls (which probably has to do with the fact that you can overload `__pos__` and `__neg__` to do pretty much whatever you want...):

```
from dis import dis

def f(x, y):
    return x ++--++ y

dis(f)
```

prints:

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 UNARY_POSITIVE
              7 UNARY_POSITIVE
              8 UNARY_NEGATIVE
              9 UNARY_NEGATIVE
             10 UNARY_POSITIVE
             11 BINARY_ADD
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Hey, great answer!

Comment: thanks and... likewise!

Comment: Appreciate you describing this from the operator overloading perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is the same as:

3+(+(+5))

Any numeric expression can be preceded by - to make it negative:

```
5-(-(3)) = 5-(-3)
         = 5+3
         = 8
```

and

```
5-(-(-3)) = 5-(3)
          = 2
```

> In Python, there are no increment operators 
>    like `++` and `--`

in C, which was probably the source of your confusion. To increment or decrement a variable i or j in Python use this style:

```
i += 1
j -= 1
```